# C++ Read binary file into uint8 array to return decimal int gives wrong result

Tags: c++, file, parsing, binary, fread

I try to parse a binary file and extract different data structures from it.
One can be an uint8 or int8 (also uint16, int16 ... till 64).

To have a most universal method, I read in the data from the given file pointer and save it in an uint8 array (buffer).

With my test, I assumed that a file content of 40 (in hex) should lead to a resulting integer 64.
That's why my test method asserts this values to be shore about it.
**
Unfortunately the uint8 array's content results always in a decimal int of 52.**
I don't know why and tries various other ways to read in a specific amount of bytes and assign them to an integer variable.
Is this a topic of endianess or something?

Thanks in advance, if someone can help :)

My read_int method:

```
int read_int(FILE * file,int n,bool is_signed) throw(){
  assert(n>0);
  uint8_t n_chars[n];
  int result;
  for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
  {
    if(fread(&n_chars[i],sizeof(n_chars[i]),1,file)!=1){
        std::cerr<< "fread() failed!\n";
        throw new ReadOpFailed();
    }
    result*=255;
    result+=n_chars[i];
  }
    std::cout<< "int read: "<<result<<"\n";
    return result;

//-------------Some ideas that didn't work out either------------------
    // std::stringstream ss;
    // ss << std::hex << static_cast<int>(static_cast<unsigned char>(n_chars)); // Convert byte to hexadecimal string
    // int result;
    // ss >> result; // Parse the hexadecimal string to integer
    // std::cout << "result" << result<<"\n";
```

One little test that tremendously fails...
The part with the endian detection gives the output for little endian (don't know if this is anyhow a part of the problem).

```
struct TestContext{
    FILE * create_test_file_hex(char * input_hex,const char * rel_file_path = "test.gguf") {
        std::ofstream MyFile(rel_file_path, std::ios::binary);

        // Write to the file
        MyFile << input_hex;

        // Close the file
        MyFile.close();

        
        // std::fstream outfile (rel_file_path,std::ios::trunc);
        // char str[20] = 
        // outfile.write(str, 20);
        // outfile.close();

        FILE *file = fopen(rel_file_path,"rb");
        try{
            assert(file != nullptr);
        }catch (int e){
            std::cout << "file couldn't be opened due to exception n° "<<std::to_string(e)<<"\n";
            ADD_FAILURE(); 
        }
        std::remove(rel_file_path); //remove file whilst open, to be able to use it, but delete it after the last pointer was deleted.
    return file;
    }
};

TEST(test_tool_functions, test_read_int){
    int n = 1;
    // little endian if true
    if(*(char *)&n == 1) {std::cout<<"Little Endian Detected!!!\n";}
    else{std::cout<<"Big Endian Detected!!!\n";}
    std::string file_hex_content = "400A0E00080000016";
    
    uint64_t should;
    std::istringstream("40") >> std::hex >> should;
    ASSERT_EQ(should,64);
    
    uint64_t result = read_int(TestContext().create_test_file_hex(file_hex_content.data()),1,false);
    ASSERT_EQ(result,should);
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please [edit] and add a language tag. Ex: [tag:c++].

Comment: This is because `54` is the ASCII (byte) code of the digit `4`, which you are writing out in text and not in a binary representation. What else did you expect? (Off-topic side note 1: Not closing the `FILE*` leaks memory. Off-topic side note 2: `FILE*` is better avoided with C++.)

Comment: @AndrejPodzimek, thanks.
I expected to read the hex value `uint8` and then convert it to the decimal value `64` which is saved in an `uint8` variable. (Thanks for the advices. The file handling is done in another module.)
Do you know how to make the function return `64`, if the file contains the hex value `40`?(see also the test I wrote for exactly this case)

Comment: I’ve added an answer. Basically you intended to write a single byte with a value 64 into the file, which you would do e.g. with `stream << '@'`. What you wrote was _de facto_ `stream << "40"`, i.e. two bytes (`stream << '4' << '0'`), the first having a value of 52 (`'4'`), the second equal to 48 (`'0'`). [Here](https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~pattis/15-1XX/common/handouts/ascii.html) are the byte values, that’s where `64 == '@'`, `52 == '4'` and `48 == '0'` come from. Try to put `@` as the first character in `file_hex_content`.

Comment: Sorry for the `54` in my first comment above. I meant `52` and can no longer edit it. (And don’t want to delete it for the sake of context keeping.)

Comment: Thanks!
Why does the test 
`uint64_t should;
    std::istringstream("40") >> std::hex >> should;
    ASSERT_EQ(should,64);`
just pass, although '40' is in this case ASCII 4 and ASCII 0 (so not 1 Byte, but 2Bytes)?

Comment: Because of different overloads of `operator >>(istream&, uint64_t)` vs `operator >>(istream&, char)`. Look what happens when you make `should` a `char`. One parses a string representation, one just reads bytes “verbatim”.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The root cause of the problem is that your `file_hex_content` consists of ASCII character bytes (which form a human-readable hexadecimal string representation of a number), not of the bytes that would form a binary integer representation. Therefore it doesn’t start with a single byte `0x40` a.k.a. `64` but with a byte `'4'` (ASCII byte value `52`) followed by another byte `'0'` (ASCII value `48`). A single byte `64` (`0x40`) [corresponds](https://www.cs.cmu.edu/%7Epattis/15-1XX/common/handouts/ascii.html) to the ASCII character `'@'` rather than two characters `'4'` and `'0'`.

A small serialization example follows. As long as you serialize and deserialize on the same architecture and have no portability concerns, endianness is not a concern either.

```cpp
#include <cstdint>
#include <ios>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>

int main() {
  std::stringstream encoded;

  const uint64_t source{0xabcd1234deadbeefULL};
  encoded.write(reinterpret_cast<const char*>(&source), sizeof(source));

  uint64_t target;
  encoded.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&target), sizeof(target));

  std::cout << "source == target: " << std::hex << source << " == " << target
            << "\nserialized bytes:";
  for (const uint8_t byte : encoded.str())
    std::cout << ' ' << static_cast<uint32_t>(byte);
  std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

The output from the program above, when [executed](https://godbolt.org/z/4W7ra9Go4) on my *little endian* machine, looks like this:

```
source == target: abcd1234deadbeef == abcd1234deadbeef
serialized bytes: ef be ad de 34 12 cd ab
```

As expected, the serialized string starts from the lowest order byte `0xef` and ends with the highest order byte `0xab`. On a *big endian* platform, the second line would be ordered from highest to lowest order byte, i.e. `ab cd 12 34 de ad be ef`.

Comment: Is there no way to read it directly into an int variable?

Comment: Depending on what you mean by _directly_. Here are two ways to get the desired `64`: `uint8_t byte; uint32_t ibyte; std::stringstream binary{"@"}; std::stringstream text{"40"}; binary.read(reinterpret_cast<char *>(&byte), sizeof(byte)); text >> std::hex >> ibyte; std::cout << std::dec << static_cast<uint32_t>(byte) << ' ' << ibyte << std::endl;`

Comment: Another (somewhat) ugly trick is the `operator >>` overload for bytes. So if `ibyte` was a `uint8_t` instead of a `uint32_t`, it would get the value of `52` (i.e. only the byte `4` would be read into it) instead of parsing and interpreting the text input and converting a string representation to integers, which is what the `uint32_t` overload does.